# C Program, Array inside a case in continuous Switch Menu loop

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement, infinite-loop

My array inside case 4 in looping Switch Menu doesn't print/display the value of the last array when the user input goes beyond array[4].

I tried to take the case 4 out and make it a single program to check if it doesn't really work on its own but it works fine, but when I put it back into the Switch, same issue again. I thought that maybe the initialization part is the problem. Help

`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char first[20],last[20];
  float math,eng,sci,avg;
  int a,b,c,d,diff,array[diff],e,i,input;
  
  do{
        printf("\nMAIN MENU\n");
    
        printf("[1] Basic Input Output\n[2] Conditional Statement\n[3] Looping Construct\n[4] Array\n[5] About\n[6] Exit");
        printf("\n\nChoose: ");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        printf("\n");
        
    switch (input)
        {
        case 1:
                printf("\nEnter your given name:");
                scanf("%s",first);
                printf("Enter your surname:");
                scanf("%s",last);
                printf("\nHello %s %s!\n",first,last);
        break;
        case 2: 
                printf("\nEnter your grade in Math:");
                scanf("%f",&math);
                printf("\nEnter your grade in Science:");
                scanf("%f",&sci);
                printf("\nEnter your grade in English:");
                scanf("%f",&eng);
    
                avg=(math+eng+sci)/3;
    
                if(math>eng&&sci)
                {
                    printf("\nHighest grade is in: Math");
                }
                if(eng>math&&sci)
                {
                    printf("\nHighest grade is in: English");
                }
                if(sci>eng&&math)
                {
                    printf("\nHighest grade is in: Science");
                }
                if(math==eng)
                {
                    printf("\n--Math and English tied grades--");
                }
                if(math==sci)
                {
                    printf("\n--Math and Science tied grades--");
                }
                if(eng==sci)
                {
                    printf("\n--Science and English tied grades--");
                }
    
                printf("\nYour average in 3 subjects:%f\n",avg);
        break;
        case 3:
                printf("Enter beginning number: ");
                scanf("%d",&b);
                printf("Enter ending number: ");
                scanf("%d",&c);
    
                printf("\nCounting from %d to %d\n",b,c);
    
                while(b<=c)
                {
                    printf("%d ",b);
                    b++;
                }
                printf("\n");
        break;
        case 4:
                printf("Enter Starting Series of Numbers: ");
                scanf("%d",&a);
                printf("Enter Ending Series of Numbers: ");
                scanf("%d",&d);
                diff=(d-a);
                array[diff]=d;
    
                printf("Select Array Value to Display: 0 to %d: ",diff);
                scanf("%d",&e);
    
                for(i=0;i<=diff;i++)
                {
                    array[i]=a;
                    if(i==e)
                    {
                        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
                    }
                    a++;
        
                }
        break;
        case 5:
                printf("Abouts\n");
        break;
        case 6:
                printf("Thank you!");
        break;
        }
        
    }while(input != 6);
    
  return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: `array[diff]` This causes undefined behaviour. You are using an undetermined value to set the size of your array. You must assign a value to `diff` first.

Comment: User will decide the size of array so I made it diff(difference) since a(Starting series of num) - d(Ending Series of num) = diff(array size). Is it wrong?

Comment: @IllustriousKage, the array  `array` gets allocated when it is declared. The value of the size variable `diff` is still `uninitialized` at this point in time, meaning it can have any value within the scope of 'int'. As a result, the array will have an unknown/invalid size.

Comment: When facing problems like these, it is always a good idea to fire up the debugger of your choice and check the values of the variables.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium, so the initialization is where the mistake is? but when I take the array part out of switch and run it as a single program it works.

Comment: Also, this part: `if(math>eng&&sci)` is the same as `if (math > eng && sci != 0)` but I'm not sure that is what you mean. Perhaps you meant `if (math > fmax(eng, sci)` ?

Comment: Undefined behaviour can appear to work or not. That's what undefined means. Therefore it can seem to work if you place the same erronous code into another program.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I don´t have enough reputation yet.

As [Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782754/gerhardh) said, the problem is that you use `diff` before being initialized (which causes undefined behaviour)

As you said, if you move the initialization of `array` inside the `case 4:` after `diff` being set the program should work as intended. If you want to keep it before the switch, try using `int*` and malloc/free inside the `case 4:` (and  add `#include <stdlib.h>`) Anyway, you should check diff as positive value before using it to set the size of `array`

About optimizing the code, you can skip the line `array[diff]=d;` because you are setting the same value inside the `for` loop. And you can remove the line  `a++;` if you changes `array[i]=a;` -> `array[i]=a+i;`